# JAXB is it possible to set an alias for a namespace

Tags: java, jaxb

I have an xml document that follows some xml schema. The problem is, unfortunately, that xml schema namespace has changed, so now I have a schema in namespace foo and document that declares namespace bar. I used xjc to make jaxb classes for the schema so they are bound to namespace foo.

Is it possible to make a jaxb unmarshaller that can unmarshall both documents in namespaces foo and bar using the same xjc generated classes?

I am expecting that you can define some property in JaxbContext that would say that namespaces foo and bar are the same... Does anyone know if something like that is supported by Jaxb providers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a SAX `XMLFilter` to adjust the namespace.

```
import org.xml.sax.*;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl;

public class NamespaceFilter extends XMLFilterImpl {

    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.example.com/ORIGINAL/NAMESPACE";

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        super.endElement(NAMESPACE, localName, qName);
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
        super.startElement(NAMESPACE, localName, qName, atts);
    }

}
```

Then use a JAXB `UnmarshallerHandler` with a SAX parser to process the input.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/11/applying-namespace-during-jaxb-unmarshal.html

Comment: Nice and clean solution. Thanks!